# update data in Mysql with a select form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a bug tracker tool.

You can add bugs to a project, and these bugs have a status (unsolved or solved).

With this select form you can change the status on the project page, all the bugs are shown in a table:

```
                <form action="classes/bugStatus.class.php" method="post">
                  <select name="status" id="status" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                       <option>-Select-</option>
                       <option value="Solved">Solved</option>
                       <option value="Unsolved">Unsolved</option>
                   </select>
                <input type='hidden' name='ID' value="<?php echo $id;?>"> 
                <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript> 
                </form>
```

With this class the status will be changed:

```
 $status = $_POST['status'];
 $id     = $_POST['ID'];

$sql="UPDATE bugs SET status = '$status'";  

 $result = mysql_query($sql); 
 $result = mysql_real_escape_string($sql); 

 if($result){
      header('Location: ../projectpage.php?id='.$id); 
      } else { 
      echo "There is something wrong. Try again later."; } 
      mysql_close();
```

The problem is, when I select something, it changes every status of every bug in that project, I don't want that. I only want to change the status of the selected bug.
In the MySQL db, the bugs each have a unique ID, so I think I have to select that bug ID as well.
I don't know how to retrieve that bug id from the database.

The form isnt sql injection proof and it isn't mysqli, I will change this later on.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="UPDATE bugs SET status = '$status'";
```

you need to update this line with `WHERE id = $id`

You're currently not specifying which bug you want to update, so you update all of them.

<del>As an added note, the community at large is going to come after you for using the old mysql extension. Take a look at [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), it'll be worth your while in the long run, I promise.</del>

oops, you've already mentioned that, nevermind.

Comment: I don't want to get the project id, I need to get the bug id, this doesn't work. Still thanks for the answer...

Comment: Then you'll need to pass the bug id to this script.

Comment: im assuming you have a bugs table in your database? just pull it when you build the form? you're already pulling bug data there right?